# List font sizes used in a psd document

Tags: adobe-photoshop, font-identification, font-size

I need a way to find out what font sizes were used in a psd document, similar to [this](https://github.com/frontendbeast/list-fonts), but for font sizes. It would be great if this way or script is compatible with older versions of PS, like CS4 and above.
Tools like Avocode and Adobe Extract support this, but I need it to work inside Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/Scribble

It lists all fonts including font sizes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. This doesn't really do it for me, its kind of slow ( don't know how fast a script should be that does this though, so slow is a relative term, but compared to the one that list the fonts, its a lot slower ), lists in pt's and not really intuitive. Best case scenario it just lists the different font sizes in pixels, and maybe the font that it was used in, but the second one is just nice to have. If anybody else wants to do this, Adobe has this thing called Extract on their website, its free, you upload the psd and you can check out a lot of stuff + export assets.